# Adicionar em BD em c#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

estou fazendo um projetinho na minha faculdade e comecei a mexer com classes em c#, porém estou encontrando problemas na hora de inserir(minha quantidade de valores no insert nao bate com values)  no meu BD e eu nao estou entendendo.
minha classe de Usuario:

```
    private int _codigo;
    private string _senha, _username;
    private byte[] _vetorImagens;

    public int Codigo
    {
        get
        {
            return _codigo;
        }

        set
        {
            _codigo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Senha
    {
        get
        {
            return _senha;
        }

        set
        {
            _senha = value;
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return _username;
        }

        set
        {
            _username = value;
        }
    }

    public byte[] VetorImagens
    {
        get
        {
            return _vetorImagens;
        }

        set
        {
            _vetorImagens = value;
        }
    }

    public string Inserir()
    {


        return "insert into Usuario(Username,Senha,Foto) values ('" + _username+ "''" + _senha + "''" + _vetorImagens +"')";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackpt! O seu código por si só não faz insert, apenas retorna uma string. Pode nos mostrar como você está fazendo o insert de fato? Também conforme resposta abaixo a sintaxe do seu SQL está errada, estão faltando vírgulas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Está faltando algumas virgulas na sintaxe do seu Insert.

Eu no seu caso faria desse jeito para melhor visualização da montagem do Insert:

```
string sql = "",
        sqlInsert = "",
        sqlValues = "";

sqlInsert += " INSERT INTO usuario(";
sqlInsert += "        Username ";
sqlInsert += "       ,Senha";
sqlInsert += "       ,Foto)";

sqlValues += " Values(";
sqlValues += "'" + _username + "',";
sqlValues += "'" + _senha + "',";
sqlValues += "'" + _vetorImagens + "')";


sql = sqlInsert + sqlValues;

return sql;
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, pq do negativo?

Comment: Query não-parametrizada é péssimo (sql inject). Não negativei porque o escopo do código fornecido pelo AP não inclui os trechos relevantes do insert, assim é mais difícil apontar como seria ideal

Comment: Entendi, no caso vale a pena editar e demonstrar o Insert utilizando o `Parameters.Add`?

Comment: Sim, seria ótimo!